# Eslint complaining about numbers with _

Tags: eslint

I have some numbers in project files, such as 1_000_000 and 1_000. I use the _ to make them easier to read, however Eslint complains about the use of _ in numbers.

How can I tell it that these numbers are valid in JavaScript?

Comment: What error message are you getting?